# How do I internationalize catalogs?

Tags: java, sql, spring, primefaces, internationalization

I have to internationalize a project, It is not only the tags of the application, I have to internationalize the Catalogs too, e.g.

Countries:

- ES : México, Alemania, Inglaterra, etc.
- EN : Mexico, Germany,England,etc

I don't want to to create a model like the next:

```
CREATE TABLE country (
  id_country INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  name_es VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  name_en VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  ....................,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_country`));
```

**Are there any best practice, pattern design or framework to solve this problem ?** because I think that is a common problem. I'm considering the next model :

```
CREATE TABLE country (
  id_country INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  languaje VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_country`));
```

The problem is that I'm going to have many foreign keys for only one country so the queries are going to be more complicated.

I'm using Java, Spring boot, Spring data, JavaServer Faces, Primefaces.

I hope that you can help me.

Thanks

Comment: I am not clear on your question here. Can you clarify?  Does your question relate to Unicode encodings?  Also what do you mean by "The problem is that I'm going to have many foreign keys for only one country so the queries are going to be more complicated."  Can you give some examples?  And what database managements system are you using?

Comment: My question is related with catalogs, like countries, cities, gender(male,female or masculino y femenino), or any catalog that you need to change in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Honestly set, I found having translations in XML most flexible, and better to incorporate in version control. Human practices were also easier.

However a database allows flexible usage, filtering, sorting etcetera.

Something which can have some evaluation use: reports, integrity checks, statistics.

```
table Texts
    id       int auto_incr -- internally
    key      varchar 30 -- public key in software
    comment  varchar 80 -- translator info, like noun, in menu
    categ    varchar 20 -- glossar entry / menu / help / tooltip
    sortkey  varchar 20 -- to order the translation
    ...

table Locales
    locale   varchar 10

table Translations
    textid   int
    locale   varchar 160
```

The idea is to *prepare* and *coordinate* work for translators.
Also translation memory formats to export / import for translating services.
A glossary is quite important to have consistent terms.
Effort put in translation at the dev side improves quality, and saves work all around.

The *production* database can be an excerpt, or even a generated java ListResourceBundle: array of strings.

Comment: But how do you use the xml for relationships?, imagine the next scenario: you have the following entities: person, country and hobbies, you need to persist a person with his birth place(country) and all its hobbies. You need to internationalize all the application, including the countries and hobbies.

Comment: From the database you get the text codes, from the user context the language, key = code + language. A text translation call holding the XML in some form then delivers the text. (Of course this is a bit simplistic.) Optimizing all can happen after the first functioning i18n.

Comment: Since it's the same comment for my answer, I will just write here that I agree with Joop.

Answer (score 1):

If sorting by the catalog title is not an issue for you, the best way is to keep the translations in your properties files, and instead of the title column in your table, add a key column in your table and use that key to reference the title according to the locale. the downside of this approach is that you can not sort the data based on the title. the upside is that you are not limited in the amount of languages you want to support.

But if sorting, grouping ... features of database queries are important, then you have no other choice than using a dictionary table, like explained in the other answers. The downside of this approach is lower performance in queries because of the to many joins with the dictionary table, and of course the risk of missing keys, will make you use outer joins with is worse performance!

The dictionary table structure will be like this :

```
CREATE TABLE dictionary(
  id INT NOT NULL,
  locale VARCHAR(2) NOT NULL,
  value VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id, locale);
```

and the for example country table will be like this :

```
CREATE TABLE country (
  id_country INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  name_dictionary_id INT NOT NULL,
  ....................,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_country`));
```

and the query that retrieves the countries list by local will be like this :

```
select 
   c.id_country, d.value
from 
   country c
left outer join dictionary d
   on (c.name_dictionary_id = d.id and d.locale = :locale)
order by d.value asc
```

the :locale is a parameter that must be sent to the query according to the user/browser requested locale.

and when you are creating new country, you need to get all the names for your supported locales and for each one, insert one dictionary, all with the same id, but different locale.

Comment: Yes I know how to use properties files, but this is useful for static content, the problem that i mentioned is related with dynamic content like catalogs, e.g. countries, imagine that i need to show countries in some selectors of my application and I need translate and save them in the database.

Comment: so the dictionary table will be the better solution for you. I can edit the answer and put a full description and design of the table for you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is a common issue and there are best practices.

For static texts that are not likely to change - like country names, the best practice is to use client-side (not DB-side) localization. In this case, you treat DB entry as key and read translations from resource files (or message source, depending how you want to implement it). JSF won't help you much here, you'd have to create your own bean to read translated names.

For dynamic text (i.e. something that changes often or could be entered by users) the best practice is to use lookup tables with a composite key:

```
CREATE TABLE translation (
  key VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  languageid VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
  translation VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`key`, `languageid`));
```

Once again, you can treat original entry as a key, but it is not recommended. Actually, it is not recommended even for static scenario - it forces you to re-use the translation of the same text. Problem is, the translation may be different based on context... So it is better to use unique translation keys, even though it means that there is no such thing as language-neutral translations.

Comment: But in this case I'm going to have n times repeated the target e.g. México, Mexico and Mejico and each of them are going to have a different primary key so if in my application i have to search the people who lives in México i have to create complex queries isn't it ?

Comment: *JSF won't help you much here, you'd have to create your own bean to read translated names* [this is **completely false**](http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/jsf-2-internationalization-example/)

Comment: @Luiggi: Please read the example you gave us. Concentrated on the Java code. Can you see it? Or should I express this more clearly?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, sorry for my English level.

I've faced your problem twice during my career.

- The first time, I remember we did the model which you don't want. We had on each datatable with texts to translate N extra columns for each language.
- The second time, we developed other model. We had a datatable for all translations + cache system (We had to show a lot of dynamic texts and we needed to improve the performance).

In both cases, before the development we knew which languages we would use. The second model would be something like that:

```
CREATE TABLE Translations (
    id_translation INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    es_ES VARCHAR(200),
    en_UK VARCHAR(200),
    ...(more languages)
    PRIMARY KEY ('id_translation')
);

CREATE TABLE Countries (
    id_country INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    id_translation INT NOT NULL,
    ...
    PRIMARY KEY ('id_country'),
    FOREIGN KEY ('id_translation')
);
```

With this model you have only one key (`id_country`) and `N` translations for this key, where N is the number of language columns in `Translations` datatable. In the future, if you need to add a new language, you'll have to add a new column in `Translations` datatable. In **your queries**, you have to `join Countries with Translations` (`id_translation`) and `SELECT` the selected language column.
If you work with **Entities (JPA)** you'll have an entity `Translation` included into an entity `Country`. With this object diagram, you can create an auxiliary JSF component to show the correct text depending the language selected.

P.S. If your application will access a lot of times to your DB to show translations, I recommend you use a cache system like Ehcache, Memcached or similar **to improve the performance**.

Comment: The problem with this model is that if you want to support a new language you need to modify your database and therefore your application, your table is going to grow in columns and not in rows, and if you support many languages for each row you are going to get all the translations and it is a huge problem if you are going to grow your application continuously.

Answer (score 0):

As it was mentioned before (in two other answers if I saw correctly), the best would be for the translation part to be out of the database, but since you want everything to be in the DB, here are my 5 cents.
I still haven't figured out how to properly format the code when posting here, so sorry about that. Also I'll write some pseudo SQL, but I hope it will be clear.

There are 3 tables:

```
CREATE TABLE country (
  id_country INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  //--optionally you could have name VARCHAR in default language
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_country`));

CREATE TABLE language(
  id_lang INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  name VARCHAR(50),
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_lang`));

CREATE TABLE countryInLanguage(
  id_country REFERENCES country.id_country, //-- FK to country table
  id_lang REFERENCES language.id_lang, //-- FK to language table
  nameInLang VARCHAR(100),
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_country, id_lang`));
```

Table countryInLanguage is called association table and represents N-to-N relationship. Sure, your queries would have to access two tables instead of one **but only** to get the name of the country in the given language. I would say that this is not much more complicated. At least it's easy to expand - in case that you are adding new countries or new languages. For everything else you would be using id_country.

There is some redundant storage being occupied here, for example there are many language n-tuples where some country name is written in the same way, but not to go too much into that...

Also you could have country name column in the country table which would hold the country name in a default language (default being most used for the specific app, user, company etc). Hell, you could even update these default values based on what user selects as a default language.

However, I must repeat (myself and others) that translations are better kept in a human readable file. Why? Often people who are translating your app don't know how to handle databases and write SQL statements and queries but if they have a text file (can be XML, key-value file...) then it's easy for them.

Comment: But how do you use the xml for relationships?, imagine the next scenario: you have the following entities: person, country and hobbies, you need to persist a person with his birth place(country) and all its hobbies. You need to internationalize all the application, including the countries and hobbies.

Comment: Why would you need relationships for translations? IMO that's way too redundant. Simply have a file for each language with key value pairs, and based on the language selected use the appropriate language file. That's how a lot of software works, for example VLC http://www.videolan.org/developers/i18n/vlc-howto.html